# how to make slew key in mfc

Tags: mfc

i have a dialog box in which a edit control and a button is presentfuncionality is that when i cliked on button edit control changes values from 0 to 30.for single click functionality is working fine but when i hold that button then it should quickly go on increasing 0 to 30 but its not going that way.it not taking left click down event.how to achecve this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Spin control, it should work as you expect.

Edit: maybe you can use AutoRepeat button: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/autorepeat.aspx

Comment: but iwant up key and down key seperately i.e in spin control key would be up and down but iwant up down key horizontaly left and right with proper gap.is there any solution?